# Is it possible to compare HTML parameter to Java Bean variable in a list?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, javabeans

I am trying to access and compare a HTML parameter to a Java Bean variable that is located in an Array List. Below is what I have but its not working when the JSP page is forwarded. The skeleton of the JSP is returned with no information received from the array.

```java
itemBean item = new itemBean();
collection coll = new collection();
List<itemBean> songs= coll.getItems();

for(int i = 0; i < songs.size(); i++) {

    if(action.equals(songs.get(i).getItemCode())) {

        item.setItemCode(songs.get(i).getItemCode());
        item.setSong(songs.get(i).getSong());
        item.setArtist(songs.get(i).getArtist());
        item.setSongURL(songs.get(i).getSongURL());
        item.setDesc(songs.get(i).getDesc());
        request.setAttribute("itemBean", item);

    }

}
```

JSP Page:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@page import="my.pack.collection" %>
    <%@include file="/header.jsp"%>
    <%@include file="/user-navigation.jsp"%>
    <%@include file="/site-navigation.jsp"%>

    <div id="productList">
        <h5><a href="categories.jsp">back</a></h5>
        <h2>Lesson 1</h2>

        <% if ((request.getAttribute("itemCode")) != null ){ %>
            <jsp:include page="item.jsp" flush="true"/>
        <% }%>
        <ul>

            <li><a>Song: ${itemBean.song}</a></li><br>
            <li><b>Artist: ${itemBean.artist}</b></li><br>
            <li><img src=${itemBean.songURL}> </li><br>
            <p> Lyrics: ${itemBean.desc}</p><br>
            <form action="feedback.jsp" method="post">

                <input type="text" name="song"/>  <br />

                <input type="text" name="artist"/><br />
                    <button type="submit" id="save"> Save! </button>
                <button type="submit" id="rate"> Rate It</button>

            </form>

        </ul>

    </div>

    <%@include file="/footer.jsp" %>
```

Collection Java: Array List of JavaBeans with the needed information.

```
 package my.pack;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */


import java.util.*;
/**
 *
 * @author Anastasia
 */
public class collection{
     private List<itemBean> Song;
    public collection(){
    Song = new ArrayList<>();
    //String itemCode;

      //itemBean item = new itemBean();
     Song.add(new itemBean("S1", "View","SHINee","Song",
     "모두 할 말을 잃지 like you<br>\n,
        "","/image/viewShinee.jpg"));

     Song.add(new itemBean("S2","Pray","FTIsland","Song",
             "또 다른 현실 속에 속삭이던 많은 거짓말<br>\n",
             "","/image/pray_FTIsland.jsp"));

     Song.add(new itemBean("S3","X","Monsta X","Song",
     "Yeah ah yeah hey hey hey<br>\n" ,
     "","/image/X_MonstaX.jpg"));

      Song.add(new itemBean("OST3","Stay With Me", "Punch & Chanyeol(EXO)","OST"," 나의 두 눈을 감으면 <br>\n" ,
      "", "/image/GoblinOST.jpg"));

     Song.add(new itemBean("OST2","Before the Sunset--Goblin OST","Eric Name", "OST",
     "나즈막히 건넨 인사가<br>\n",
     "","/image/MadDogOST.jpg"));

    Song.add(new itemBean("OST3","You Are My Everything", "Gummy","OST",
     "처음부터 그대였죠<br>\n" ,
     "","/image/DOTS.jpg"));


}
    public List<itemBean> getItems(){
        return Song;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which technique are you using to access the request attribute ("itemBean") on your JSP page? Maybe you could post the essential part of the page.

Comment: @Renardo Sorry thats the coding for the JSP page

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the error might be that you do not have `request.` in your EL; Have you tried `${request.itemBean.song}` ?

You should really:

1. Start variable names with a lower case letter
2. Start class names with a capital letter
3. Use a `Map<String, ItemBean>` to hold your song collection
4. Use meaningful names like Song instead of ItemBean

Comment: Coll isn't empty I don't believe I posted the coding for the Collection class

Comment: Is `action` set from a request parameter? What is its value?

Comment: @Renardo This is how it is set String action= request.getParameter("itemCode");

Comment: @jan-larsen: You just wrote that after calling the default constuctor `coll` is empty. But the `collection` class has a default constructor that populates the list so it is not empty. That's very strange but Anastasia seems to have a different coding style than you and me. Anastasia, I would still like to know what value the request specifies for `itemCode`. Maybe you should print it in the program. Some tracing could be useful to see what happens.

Comment: @Renardo I ran a debug for what was being compared to by adding a variable within the for loop and setting it equal to songs.get(i).getItemCode(); and it is returning "". So the if statement isnt getting the itemCode from the array List

Comment: O.k. So there is a problem in your `itemBean` class (if you want to do more Java you should really start your class names with a capital letter): Somehow the value from the constructor does not make it to the getter method. Surely you do not need help to identify that problem.